# Rails: Formtastic field with description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

how is it possible to add a description to a form field made with formtastic?

I tried this:

```
f.input :first_name, description: 'Please insert your first_name'
```

The description should appear right under the form field.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no description option for formtastic fields, but you can use :hint option instead

```
f.input :first_name, :hint => 'Please insert your first_name'
```